# Swagger Annotations don't show a body example

Tags: swagger-2.0

When working with Swagger Annotations it is not possible to create an example for the request body.

[image: Generated Swagger page but the Json is missing]

Here comes the annotation stuff for the RESTful resource/endpoint:

```
 @POST
@Path("/{carId}/conversation")
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Authorization", value = "The AppJWT token", paramType = "header", required = true),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "ON-BEHALF", value = "The ConsumerJWS token", paramType = "header", required = true),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "v", value = "API version", defaultValue = "3", paramType = "query", required = true)
})
@ManagedAsync
@ApiOperation(value = "bla", notes = "")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "bla", response = CreateBlaResponse.class, responseContainer = "List"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "The input was invalid, please check.", response = GenericError.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized. Are the headers correct?"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 429, message = "Too many requests, please try again later", response = CreateConversationResBody.class)
})
public void createConversationBatchPOST(@ApiParam(value = "Car ID the action should apply to", required = true) @PathParam("carId") String carId,
                                        @ApiParam(name = "body", value = "The Json payload", required = true, examples = @Example(value = {@ExampleProperty(value = "{\"name\" : \"James\"}", mediaType = "application/json")}))
                                        @RequestBody String body,
                                        @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) throws IOException {
//.... implementation
}
```

Do you have an idea why the annotation in the method signature

```
     @ApiParam(name = "body", value = "The Json payload", 
required = true, examples = @Example(value = {@ExampleProperty(value = "{\"name\" : \"James\"}", mediaType = "application/json")})) 
@RequestBody String body
```

doesn't lead to the Json example?

Comment: This is the version in use: 
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.17</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: I think it has anything to do with the fact that the payload is of type String.

Comment: Swagger doesn't support defining an array with different objects, see also: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/57#issuecomment-239226502